# Python - decorator function using lambda function for a class

Tags: python, oop, lambda, decorator

I was checking some code online on how to track step of a specific pipeline and I got to the following code:

```
class Pipeline():
    def __init__(self, step_id, fct_to_call):
        self.step_id = step_id
        self.fct_to_call = fct_to_call

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.fct_to_call(*args)

def pipeline_step(step_id):
    return lambda f: Pipeline(step_id=step_id, fct_to_call=f)

@pipeline_step(step_id='lacocouracha')
def my_sum(numba):
    output = numba *1.45
    return output

a = my_sum(12)
```

My question is related to when we are using the lambda function. When I run in debugger mode, I see that the lambda function 'f' is referring to 'my_sum'. So when using a lambda function inside a decorating function, it will automatically understand that it is the decorated function it wants as input?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `pipeline_step` is not the decorator; it *returns* a decorator, which is the function that takes the decorated function as an argument.

`pipeline_step` could have been written using a `def` statement as well, which can make it more explicit:

```
def pipeline_step(step_id):
    def decorator(f):
        return Pipeline(step_id=step_id, fct_to_call=f)
    return decorator
```

When you call `pipeline_step(step_id='lacocouracha')`, it returns a new function `decorator` (which acts as a closure around the variable `step_id`). `decorator` then receives the function `my_sum` as its argument, and the name `my_sum` is rebound to the instance of `Pipeline` returned by `decorator`.

Using the lambda expression simply skips the step of having to come up with a name for the decorator, which will never be visible or used outside of `pipeline_step` itself.

---

For completeness, a reminder that

```
@pipeline_step(step_id='lacocouracha')
def my_sum(numba):
    output = numba *1.45
    return output
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def my_sum(numba):
    output = numba *1.45
    return output

my_sum = pipeline_step(step_id='lacocoracha')(my_sum)
# == (lambda f: Pipeline(step_id=step_id, fct_to_call=f))(my_sum)
# == Pipeline(step_id=step_id, fct_to_call=my_sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, make me understood better. I could also do: ```pipeline_step(step_id='lacocoracha')(my_sum)(12)```